# youtube api returning error on Android only

Tags: android, cordova, google-api

I've built an android app and matching website, and I can get responses from the web no problem, but when I open the app I get an error

```
403: ""Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
```

I'm using an Android Application Key for the android app, and a Browser Applications Key for the Phonegap App. Should Phonegap be using the Browser Application Key? If so, what is the referrer?

If I'm supposed to use the Android Applicatoin Key, I'm guessing it has something to do with the key I've provided to google through the developer console, though maybe somebody else has another solution.

At the end of the sha1 hash in the dev dashboard it asks for a your keystore sha1, followed by a `name`. I'm guessing this name might be the issue. I've used the same name as I used for my app in phonegap `com.newstube.demo`.

Does anybody know if that would cause this issue? Does that name need to be unique across google? Does it need to match something? Is something else completely causing this issue?